# SQLITE create statement error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 in python3.

Is there anything wrong in my `CREATE` statement shown below?
`c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transaction(no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  ic NONE, borrow INTEGER, timeIn NONE, timeOut NONE")`

Error message: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "transaction" : syntax error`

Answer (score 1):

"transaction" is a reserved word in SQL. You need to [quote](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) it if you want to use it.

```
... `transaction` (...
```

Answer (score 1):

As `Ignacio` said, `transaction` should be quoted and there is a missing right parenthesis.
The query should looks like:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'transaction'(no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  
                                                    ic NONE, borrow INTEGER, 
                                                    timeIn NONE, 
                                                    timeOut NONE)")
```